# why this xpath is not working

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am scrapying over this page

http://www.modeluxproperties.com/?m=search&web=1&act=details_web&id=503

I want to get the values of all the `Amenities`

my xpath is

```
normalize-space(.//div[@id='specimen']/div[@class='section']/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr/td/text())
```

I got an empty results, **why please?**

Comment: I don't see a table element in tr[4]. i think you've repeated table/tr

Comment: @deanosaur no i completely see the table in tr[4] . check firebug if you want

Comment: I think you mean `tr[3]`, `tr[4]` does not contain any table

Comment: I see the table in tr[4] now, but it looks like its got <td><img>text</img></td>

Comment: I insist on seing tables only in `tr[0]` (2 tables) and `tr[3]` (1 table)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: start by looking into the actual result of `.//div[@id='specimen']/div[@class='section']/table//tr[4]/td`, verify that there are no table there, then check for `tr[3]`

Comment: Also, should we start considering that the content of the web page is not entirely static and the tables may be dynamically present or absent?

Comment: @njzk2 no the table existed in tr[4], I can see it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct xpath for amenities is:

```
"//table//div[@id='specimen']//table/tr[4]/td/table/tr/td/text()"
```

so your xpath is actually completely ok, perhaps you are extracting it in some strange way?You can extract it like so:

```
sel.xpath("//table//div[@id='specimen']//table/tr[4]/td/table/tr/td/text()").extract()
```

where sel is simply an instance of Selector, created like so `sel = Selector(response)`.

To debug that kind of issues Firefox firepath extension is very helpful, for Chrome there is xpath helper.Typically you should start with finding the right xpath with firepath and then trying it in scrapy shell, it's really simple something like:

```
scrapy shell
fetch "http://[your url]"
```

then you will get selector object sel, and you can test your xpath there. Testing with scrapy shell is often necessary because browsers are modifying html displayed on pages. For example in case of tables most browsers add tbody to tables.